# How to dynamically import package in react and catch import errors without breaking app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, node-modules

I'm trying to dynamically import from my dependencies using a for loop like so

```
const packageNames = [
    '@packageA/address',
    '@packageB/app',
    '@packageC/auth',
]

    for await (const packageName of packageNames) {
        try {
            const importedPackage = await import(`${packageName}/custom-components`);
            console.log('importedPackage :', importedPackage);
            // Do something with the imported package
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error importing ${packageName}: ${error}`);
        }
    }
```

I want to import `custom-components` from those `packageNames` and if it fails just to catch the error and log it.

But instead, it breaks the app if the `custom-components` file doesn't exist in the package I'm trying to import from.

One solution I was thinking of would be to use the `fs` package to check if `custom-components` file exists in the package but that's not possible to do in a React app.

Is there any other way to get around this, to just catch the error instead of breaking the app with an error like `Can't resolve '@packageA/address/custom-components'`

Comment: I get the `Compiled with problems: Can't resolve '@packageA/address/custom-components'` error.

Comment: That implies a compiler is involved somewhere. You haven't mentioned one. Are you using TypeScript? A bundler of some kind (Webpack, Rollup, Vite, Rome, etc.)? Just dynamic import, itself, won't give you that problem, just the module load error that you're capturing and "handling" by writing it to the console. You'll need to consult the documentation of the the tool you're getting the error from to figure out how to handle optional imports (if it even supports them).

Comment: Using TypeScript and the bundler is Webpack. So it turned out to be an error for Dev mode. Once the app is built and running from `dist` the error is caught as expected for me and the app is working as expected.